# delete item from localstorage ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, html

i have some data in localstorage it look's like this `shotemup_dslfjsdlfjsdf_1395732812679 8` (key, value), after some action i need to send this data to server and if it was success i need to delete 1 row from localstorage

```
for(var i=0, len=localStorage.length; i<len; i++) {
                var name = localStorage.key(i);
                var score = localStorage[name];
                console.log(name + " " + score);
                title = name.substring(0, name.indexOf('_'));
                username = name.substring(name.indexOf('_') + 1, name.lastIndexOf('_'));
                var toDelete = name;
                if(title == "shotemup"){
                    $.ajax({
                        type: "POST",
                        url: "/scores",
                        data : {name : username, score : score },
                        statusCode :{
                            400: function() {
                                console.log("Wrong data");
                            },
                            200: function(){
                                console.log(toDelete);
                            }
                        },

                    });
                }
            }
```

but when i log what i want to delete i have same rows(at 200 code handler)
for example i have in localstorage
`shotemup_123_1395733862023 8235
shotemup_2342_1395733866192 8235
shotemup_dslfjsdlfjsdf_1395732812679 8` in localstorage 200 code handler will log `shotemup_dslfjsdlfjsdf_1395732812679` 3 times

Answer (score 3):

You can use the [removeItem()](http://dev.w3.org/html5/webstorage/#dom-storage-removeitem) method

```
for (var i = 0, len = localStorage.length; i < len; i++) {
    //use a closure to escape the loop variable
    (function(i){
        var name = localStorage.key(i);
        var score = localStorage[name];
        console.log(name + " " + score);
        title = name.substring(0, name.indexOf('_'));
        username = name.substring(name.indexOf('_') + 1, name.lastIndexOf('_'));
        var toDelete = name;
        if (title == "shotemup") {
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "/scores",
                data: {
                    name: username,
                    score: score
                },
                statusCode: {
                    400: function () {
                        console.log("Wrong data");
                    },
                    200: function () {
                        console.log(toDelete);
                        //remove item with the given name
                        localStorage.removeItem(name)
                    }
                },

            });
        }

    })(i);
}
```

Comment: oh i see the differense

Answer (score 0):

Well you can use these methods given below :-

```
localStorage.removeItem('name');
```

This method for remove single and particulate item from localStorage.

```
localStorage.clear();
```

This method use for copmletely clear your localStorage.